# Mixing SRAM AXS and Eagle cassette

Tags: chain, groupsets

I know it's possible to put an Eagle 10-50 cassette on a road bike with a Sram Force AXS 1x groupset, as I rode a Santa Cruz Stigmata with this exact spec.

My question is about running the Force 2x with the same Eagle cassette.  Basically I want to know if that would work and the question is technically about the chain.

I was surprised that the Force 1x with Eagle in this setup doesn't use the new asymmetric chain with a flat side, rather an Eagle chain.  If I were to convert this bike to a 2x Force crankset, would that same Eagle chain work?  If not, would the standard 12 speed chain work with that Eagle cassette?